# Select consecutive emails in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail webpage, can I select a list of consecutive emails without clicking one by one? Note that I am not selecting all the emails shown at a screen, but only a subset of consecutive emails.

An ideal solution will be clicking the first email in the list, and then press shift key and at the same time select the last email in the list. But that doesn't work in Gmail webpage.

Comment: What browser are you using? It works exactly that way when I try it in Gmail.

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work. But it does now.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of Gmail tips online that cover this, including this from [lifewire.com](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-select-multiple-messages-quickly-in-gmail-1172037):

> 1. Check the first message in the range with the mouse.
>
>    - ​Click the checkbox in front of the message.
> 2. Hold down the *Shift* key and
> 3. check the last message in the desired range with the mouse.

So your assumption of how it *should* work is exactly how it *does* work. If it doesn't, then perhaps you've misclicked, some bit of JavaScript didn't load (an ad-blocker, maybe?), your browser is too old, or some other glitch.